# CSS for mobile sometimes reverts back to original

Tags: css, asp.net, media-queries

So most of the time my stylesheets appear properly.  The standard/original one always works flawlessly, however it seems sometimes the mobile one is disregarded when looked at from a mobile device

I have them designated as follows:

```
<link href="CustomStyleSheets/standard.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="CustomStyleSheets/mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 799px)" />
```

I'm using a Droid X to view the page, in portrait mode, so the device width shouldn't be exceeding the max-width specified above, but sometimes, randomly, it still reverts back to the original css page.

Any way to keep it from doing so?

Comment: could be a bug in android browser, does this happen on iphone or opera for android

Comment: If I remember correctly it happens on iphone as well, but we're having some issues with our mac this morning, so I haven't been able to test it yet on the emulator... and no one in my dept owns an iphone.

Comment: does the same happen when you use `max-width: 799px` ?

Comment: Does the same problem occur in landscape mode?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your standard.css isn't affecting the cascade of what you expect to see with the mobile.css. It looks as though a mobile device will load your standard.css first then the mobile.css - so styles in both stylesheets are affecting display. I usually wrap my stylesheet link elements in logic that only displays a mobile stylesheet to a mobile device - not both stylesheets at the same time.

Also, don't forget to include this meta tag to make sure your page is being scaled correctly to the device dimensions:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Comment: _I usually wrap my stylesheet link elements in logic that only displays a mobile stylesheet to a mobile device - not both stylesheets at the same time._  <-- Please elaborate.  How do you wrap them in logic? Do you use javascript or something?

Comment: I think he's saying to add a condition to your first CSS Import, so that it doesn't get loaded too.  Something to the nature of media="All (min-width:800)" <i>might</i> help the browser avoid loading the conflicting desktop version of the CSS along with the "mobile version".

Answer (score 0):

Try using the media type "handheld".

```
<link href="CustomStyleSheets/standard.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="CustomStyleSheets/mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="handheld" />
```

Comment: Caveat to be aware of: iPhone does not support the media type handheld so this would not have the desired effect at least in iPhone. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893342/do-iphone-android-browsers-support-css-media-handheld

Comment: @Jim - you're correct.  Most of the newer touch screen devices don't support handheld very well, if at all.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe use media="screen" for standard.css? Maybe it helps (:

Or check user-agent in server side. If it is mobile device loading only mobile css otherwise load standard.css.

I use WURFL to find out if it is mobile device...

Answer (score -1):

I've see that happen before.  I believe it was the size of the body element that was getting changed.  The correct doctype is important.  It should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
```

Comment: Actually that WAP docType, though perfectly valid for some devices such as Blackberry - is not needed on iPhone/Android, which work perfectly well with the HTML5 doctype eg, just: <!DOCTYPE html>