# handheld css does not work properly

Tags: css, mobile, handheld

on my site i have 3 css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="screen.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="handheld" href="handheld.css" />
```

i thought the media handheld will automatically load my site formated for devices

when i load my site with my android, i still see the "site.css" why it does not load the handheld.css?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apparently Android/iPhone/Nokia browsers don't think that they are handhelds.

You should use [media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893342/do-iphone-android-browsers-support-css-media-handheld) to detect devices.

Comment: so which one are handheld? so is it better to use the media queries to make sure all mobile is correct?

Comment: handheld in my understanding are those running Opera Mini, but even with Opera Mini user may need to enable portable mode explicitly

Comment: `handheld` https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html#media-types **is** actually part of media queries, so if they don't think to be handhelds don't see how it can help...

Comment: This is a shame. It's literally the standard, why we still have to use width/height trickery for detecting handheld devices?