# 'Active' instead of :hover for touch devices

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using `:hover` to show a make a menu opaque when the mouse hovers over - obviously this doesn't work for touch devices. This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wright_jamie/veDU3/1/) shows what I'm trying to achieve (scroll down to see the transparency). In my full example I'm using checkboxes to drop down the sub-menus, which is working great.

Obviously I can't traverse 'upwards' using CSS, so selecting a checkbox I can't affect the grandparent `nav`. Does anyone have any suggestions? Is there some sort of `:active` or equivalent that traverses up the DOM?

I'm not sure I'm making myself particularly clear, but any help would be appreciated. I suspect the only solution might be a jquery one?

Comment: Yes, you'd use javascript for this. (or ideally, don't design interactions that depend on hover)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simpler to just avoid the opacity effect completely on mobile. That is, set opacity to 1 if the client is on a touch device.

Comment: Stupidly simple! I've already got a `touch` class through modernizer. Why didn't I think of that!

Answer (score 1):

Use media queries to do something else for handheld devices;

```
@media handheld {
    /* .myHoverElement:active { }*/
}
```

You could try and look for some touch devices too that you specifically want to target. For example;

iPhone < 5:

```
@media handheld and (device-aspect-ratio: 2/3) {}
```

iPhone 5:

```
@media handheld and (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71) {}
```

iPad:

```
@media handheld and (device-aspect-ratio: 3/4) {}
```

As for the comment that `cimmanon` stated. StackOverflow has quite some info about it and how to target specific devices and maybe detect them better if `handheld` would not work on certain devices;

[Do iPhone / Android browsers support CSS @media handheld?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893342/do-iphone-android-browsers-support-css-media-handheld)

Comment: Do any modern mobile devices respond to `handheld`?  Every source I've seen says no.