# HTML Navigation Menu for iphone/tablets

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a menu that can be used on mobile or smaller devices since the `ul` menu goes off the screen on those with a lower resolution. Below is the code I'm trying to use, but for some reason it isn't working. The drop down box works fine but clicking on the options doesn't do anything.

Firstly the HTML:

```
<select> 
            <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option> 
            <option value="index.html">Home</option> 
            <option value="about.html">About Us</option> 
            <option value="testimonials.html">Testimonials</option> 
            <option value="events.html">Events</option> 
            <option value="contracts.html">Contracts</option> 
            <option value="faq.html">F.A.Q.</option> 
            <option value="contact.html">Contact Us</option> 
</select>
```

Now, the JS.

```
<script>$("select").change(function() {
window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
});</script>
```

Now, the CSS to hide it on normal browsers but show it on small devices.

```
select
  {
  display:none;
  }

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  nav  { display: none; }
  select { display: inline-block; }
  }
```

I've checked my coding again and again, but I can't seem to get it to work. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: have you included jQuery script in your HTML? it's working here: http://jsfiddle.net/uAd5j/

Comment: Are you testing it on iphone? Becuase I click the menu, and it shows the roller thing, but clicking on the options just makes them selected and nothing happens. I even tried them on two empty html files and still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

[Do iPhone / Android browsers support CSS @media handheld?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3893342/1848109)

Refer the question for media queries in CSS. Optionally you can use Jquery to get the screen size and reflect the changes at UI level.

Check the iphone and tablet compatibility to the CSS3 media queries.

The **Jsfiddle** link posted by  **hmhcreative** is working. It should work for iphone or tablets too.