# media query is not working on mobile but on desktop it works great

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive

HTML head-

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="viewport" content="maximum-scale=1">
```

CSS media query-

```
@media handheld, screen 
  and (min-width: 200px)
  and (max-width: 399px){}
```

Comment: This is your query?

Comment: Maybe try @media only screen and min-device-width: 200px) {
}

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why you using handheld.. I just post my answer media query for mobile.

`@media only screen and (min-width:300px) and (max-width :399px)
{
}`

Comment: I do that as well and still nothing

Answer (score 0):

First, `handheld` is not supported by most mobile browsers, you can see more from this question: [Do iPhone / Android browsers support CSS @media handheld?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893342/do-iphone-android-browsers-support-css-media-handheld)

Second, the breakpoint of your `@media` doesn't quite match any mobile screen size, here a website listing media queries for standard devices that your can check on: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: I have about 15 media queries because at each something is added and shifted to fit the exactly right on desktop it works completely fine