# Table td display:block on Apple devices will not work

Tags: android, ios, css

Just confused - I have this css rule on my table making the table stack on mobile. Seems to work fine in Chrome and android.

But on the apple devices it is not stacking and I cannot work out why, If anyone has any idea why could you please let me know.

```
@media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 480px){table td {
display: block!important;
clear: both;
width: 100%!important;}}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do iPhone / Android browsers support CSS @media handheld?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893342/do-iphone-android-browsers-support-css-media-handheld)

Comment: Nope i dont think it is.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out it was the .doctype